# Finding the maximum element in a stack in constant time

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stack

While trying to solve this problem from [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/), I wrote up the following code which passes 22/27 test case. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the test cases for which it failed.
**Problem**
You have an empty sequence, and you will be given ***N*** queries. Each query is one of these three types:

> 1 x => Push the element x into the stack.
> 2 => Delete the element present at the top of the stack.
> 3 => Print the maximum element in the stack.

*Input Format*
The first line of input contains an integer, ***N***. The next ***N*** lines each contain an above mentioned query. (It is guaranteed that each query is valid)
*Constraints*
`1 <= N <= 10^5`
`1 <= x <= 10^9`
`1 <= type <= 3`
*Output Format*
For each type ***3*** query, print the maximum element in the stack on a new line.
*Sample Input*

> 10
> 1 97
> 2
> 1 20
> 2
> 1 26
> 1 20
> 2
> 3
> 1 91
> 3

*Sample Output*

> 26
> 91

My approach to solving this problem was -

1. Use one vector to hold the state of the stack
2. Use another vector to hold max values entered

And my solution is as below -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   
    vector<int> myvect;        /* Vector to hold the inputs */
    vector<int> mymax;         /* Vector to hold max elements */
    unsigned times;
    unsigned type;
    unsigned x;
    cin >> times;
    if (times <= 100000) {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            cin >> type;
            if (type >= 1 && type <= 3) {
                switch (type) {
                    case 1:
                        cin >> x;
                        if (x <= 1000000000) {
                            myvect.push_back(x);
                            if (mymax.empty())
                                mymax.push_back(x);
                            else if (x > mymax.back())
                                    mymax.push_back(x);
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (!myvect.empty()) {
                            if (!mymax.empty() && (myvect.back() == mymax.back()))
                                mymax.pop_back();
                            myvect.pop_back();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        cout << mymax.back() << endl;
                        break;
                    default:
                        cout << "We should not get in here" << endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody please help me figure out the bug or corner cases that I have missed in my code so I can fix it and it passes all the test cases?

Comment: You can speed things up by maintaining a "running" maximum.  Use a variable that contains the maximum value pushed.  When command 3 is entered, print the variable.  When a deletion from the stack occurs, you may have to determine the max value.

Comment: Your solution worked as well! This was very similar to my initial approach except I was calling `find_max()` everytime `option 3` is entered and that resulted in timeout for HackerRank platform for certain test cases. However, after incorporating the optimization you suggested (maintaining a "running" maximum and calling `find_max()` only when we pop from the stack), it worked out perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you only add to mymax if x > mymax.back(). So, if x == mymax.back() you do not do anything. Now imagine, that 1, 3, 3, 3, 3 are inserted into the stack. In this case your "mymax" has only one 3 and as soon as a query of type "delete" arrives your max will become 1; however, the true answer is 3. Fixing this will give you the right answer.

However, for problems like this I usually use a "multiset" data structure in c++. And whatever is inserted into stack is inserted into multiset as well (same thing for delete). However, multiset can be updated O(logn) time. And it can report the maximum element in O(1).

Since N <= 10^5. The complexity of this algorithm will be O(N log N) which is still very reasonable.

Note that multiset is very similar to set data structure with the exception that you can have **repeated** numbers which in your problem is very helpful.

Comment: i kinda disagree with you, the reason is multiset is implemented via red-black tree /AVL, each action takes O(lgn) by far not a constant time, the answer can be max-heap and read the root ->reading it will be at O(1) regardless of the amout of values inserted or deciding that max element will be in a specific location in a vector/array since they provide O(1) (not as expected value) i would insert my elements to a max heap and that's it

Comment: Set and Multiset can return the element with highest priority in constant time. In fact, *s.begin() will return the element with highest priority. (we use a * to return the content of the iterator s.begin()). Delete and Insert in set, multiset, map, (which are all red-black tree) take O(logn).

Comment: sry you're actually right , set and multiset are ordered and if you put greater in the comparison function/functor you get it in s.begin() as you've said! my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cool python solution for this problem, you just need to use two stacks.

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    stack = []
    stack_for_max = [-sys.maxsize]

    for i in range(0, int(input())):
        data = str(input())
        if " " in data:
            data_to_be_added = int(data.split(" ")[1])
            stack.append(data_to_be_added)

            if data_to_be_added >= stack_for_max[-1]:
                stack_for_max.append(data_to_be_added)

        elif data == "2":
            top_of_the_stack = stack.pop()
            if top_of_the_stack == stack_for_max[-1]:
                stack_for_max.pop()

        else:
            print(stack_for_max[-1])
```

Comment: You can do it with one stack by just always pushing `max(data_to_be_added, stack[-1])`. You don't need to keep elements which aren't the current maximum.